# Múltipla seleção de radiobutton

Tags: jquery, html, radiobutton

Estou fazendo um formulário de cadastro que tem o link **Adicionar mais campos** e quando a pessoa clica nele, multiplica os campos do formulário. Um desses campos do formulário são 2 radios buttons, que são **"Tem filhos? ( ) Sim ( ) Não"** , e quando clica para adicionar mais campos a seleção que está no **( ) Sim** (por padrão) ele some e vai para o campo que foi adicionado; e se eu clico para selecionar o radio button de cima, ele sai do de baixo e vai para o de cima, então dentre os 4 radio buttons que tenho no formulário, eu só posso selecionar 1. O nome dos radiobuttons estão assim **name="filhos[]"** mas não estão funcionando.

**Código jQuey (multiplicado)**

```
<script>   $("a#adicionarMaisCampos").on('click', function(){

    var html = '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>Nome</td><td><input type="text" name="nome[]" class="form-control"></td></tr><tr><td>Data de aniversário:</td><td><input type="text" name="nascimento[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Somente o dia e mês. ex: 12/04"></td></tr><tr><td>Filhos:</td><td><input type="radio" name="filhos[]" value="1">Sim <input type="radio" name="filhos[]" value="2" checked> Não</td></tr><tr><td>Profissão:</td><td><input type="text" name="profissao[]" class="form-control"></td></tr><tr><td>Sexo</td><td><input type="radio" name="sexo[]" value="1" checked> Masculino<input type="radio" name="sexo[]" value="2"> Feminino</td></tr><tr><td>Email:</td><td><input type="email" name="email[]" class="form-control"></td></tr><tr><td>Celular:</td><td><input type="text" name="celular[]" class="form-control"></td></tr><tr><td>Cargo:</td><td><input type="text" name="cargo[]" class="form-control"></td></tr>';

   $("#more").after(html);


  });   </script>
```

**HTML**

```
<tr>
                      <td>Nome</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="nome[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>Data de aniversário:</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="nascimento[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Somente o dia e mês. ex: 12/04"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>Filhos:</td>
                      <td><input type="radio" name="filhos[]" value="1">Sim <input type="radio" name="filhos[]" value="2" checked> Não</td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>Profissão:</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="profissao[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>Sexo</td>
                      <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="sexo[]" value="1" checked> Masculino <input type="radio" name="sexo[]" value="2"> Feminino
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>Email:</td>
                      <td><input type="email" name="email[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>Celular:</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="celular[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr id="more">
                      <td>Cargo:</td>
                      <td><input type="text" name="cargo[]" class="form-control"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                      <td><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="adicionarMaisCampos"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Adicionar mais campos</a></td>
                    </tr>
```

Comment: O name de todos os radiobuttons estão iguais?

Comment: No ato de multiplicar os campos do formulário, você deve alterar o name dos dois novos RadioButtons. Se você puder postar o código que faz essa multiplicação eu posso elaborar uma resposta mais direta.

Comment: @Vinícius sim, pois no PHP estou pegando $_POST['filhos'] e fazendo um loop com `foreach` para pegar todos (caso tenha + de 1)

Comment: @Vinícius adicionei o código

Comment: o HTML por padrão utiliza o name dos inputs para realizar o match. Ao colocar quatro radiobuttons com o mesmo name, ele irá identificar como se fossem quatro opções em vez de apenas 2. Não sou desenvolvedor PHP, mas estou verificando aqui como posso te ajudar.

Comment: @Vinícius é que isso facilitaria para mim, pois se eu colocasse 2 nomes iguais, depois outros 2 nomes iguais mas diferentes dos outros 2 e assim por diante, iria ser MUITO trabalhoso na verificação PHP

Comment: Mas pelo que eu entendi Alisson, são realmente dois atributos não é? Se existem dois na tela, no seu backend também deveriam existir outros dois, pois os valores podem ser diferentes.

Comment: Inicialmente serão 2 radios buttons com o mesmo nome com os valores sim ou não. Só que quando o usuário clicar em adicionar mais ele então adiciona +2 radios buttons com o mesmo nome e o mesmo valor Sim ou Não. E no PHP ele não vai saber se clicou no link pra adicionar mais a não ser que eu deixe o mesmo nome (da forma q está agora) e faça um loop

Comment: Amigo, você deve gerar `name` diferente pra todos os campos radio e antes de enviar salvar num array e enviar esses arrays para o servidor. Acho que é a única forma de fazer.